# PHP Error: ratchet/pawl and TLS

Tags: php, ssl, websocket, wss

I am having trouble narrowing down this issue with my WSS connection. I am trying to use the composer library "[ratchet/pawl](https://github.com/ratchetphp/Pawl)" to make an async websockets client connection to a server. I am however running into a little TLS issue; error quoted below. I am using Laravel (at time of writing: 5.4.23) with PHP 7.1 on a shared webhosting server.

> Could not connect: Unable to complete SSL/TLS handshake:
>   stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1.
>   OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL
>   routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

I've tried searching *everywhere* to see if maybe someone else has run into this problem, but google is flooded with SMTP results related to the same problem, which as you can imagine is a bit of a problem in itself. The only thing i've been able to come up with is using some ProxyPass voodoo, is this really the right way?

This is my first post and I hope this is descriptive enough if you need any additional information I would be happy to oblige. Thanks!

update: i've opened a bug report with the developer [here](https://github.com/ratchetphp/Pawl/issues/47)

Comment: For anyone trying to suppress self-signed certificate errors the solution is at https://github.com/ratchetphp/Pawl/issues/72#issuecomment-362371067 (pass ['tls' => ['verify_peer' => false, 'verify_peer_name' => false] as $options to the Connector constructor).